# Is 1170px too wide for a responsive WordPress site, or is their an ideal maximum width?

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive WordPress-based website (with all the media queries that auto adjust when you adjust the width of the site) and I currently have it set to 980px in width.

My content area is only 600 px in width, as my sidebar and margins/wraps take up the rest of the width.

**Current:**

--------------content 600px-------------|--sidebar+margins = 980 px

I'd like to have a **wider content area** without altering the sidebar/margins/wraps.

Because this is a high quality responsive theme, is there any danger in setting the full width to, say, 1170px? This would make the content area 790px, which would be much more manageable for me.

**Desired - but appropriate, if responsive?**

-----------------------content 790px----------------------|--sidebar+margins = 1170 px

Or will this just totally screw things up on Iphones/tablets, etc.?  Thanks for any guidance anybody can offer!

Comment: What do you mean by “responsive”? The question seems to be about designing for a specific width and asking about the best width (which is basically an opinion poll), so the approach seems to be the exact opposite of responsive design.

Comment: Thanks Jukka.  It's the Catalyst Framework/Dynamik Child Theme and they just have a ton of different media queries for various sizes.  The documentation they give is http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design and the theme just allows you to click a specific layout (or adjust the media queries in your CSS yourself).  I think I'll try 1170 and see how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have so many templates using 1170px and no problems with this when it's responsible. Working in every iphones, ipads and tablets.

I've recommend you to install in your browser (chrome) a plugin called Window Resizer. That will help you when you are developing this.

Comment: Thanks Frank for taking the time to respond.  It's the Catalyst Framework for WordPress; I paid $127 for it.  They just give you a list of a set of icons to choose from when choosing your "responsive" design for various tablets ... or you can adjust the @media queries yourself in the CSS.  But if you're saying 1170 works with no problems, I'm confident Catalyst is responsible. I'll give it a go.  their documentation is blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design ... thanks again, and thanks for the tip to that Chrome add-on -- I had never heard of it!

Comment: Hi. I see that for the first time. Catalyst Framework for wordpress. As I see, it's a good tool. Anyway, I love the bootstrap framework and it makes my websites or wordpress themes very lightness.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I found a way online to make my site fluid AND responsive and it's set at 1170, just like the Bootstrap.  So it looks good on all sizes in Chrome's Window Resizer now.  It does take a lot of CSS work.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second Franks answer, and also would like to add that the content is always the determinant of the appropriate size. I've pushed sites as big as 1280 on the upper limit.

Responsive Web Design tends to focus a lot on small screens, but smart TV's and other big screen devices pose a whole new set of challenges, and big allowing for bigger widths is a great thing for end users.

Comment: Thanks Chris .. I was able to find some techniques on css-tricks or maybe it was here, but a couple tricks to make my site responsive AND fluid ... and I'm really liking the look right now.

Comment: Awesome, Jason! CSS-Tricks is a goldmine of resources. I've also found the [Foldy 960 grid](https://github.com/davatron5000/Foldy960) quite useful, to the point that I built an entire [open source boilerplate](http://cferdinandi.github.io/kraken/) around it. Best of luck, and feel free to reach out directly if you have any questions or want to bounce some ideas around.